# Swap partition on VPS

Tags: server, swap, disk-usage, vps

Sorry that this is a very similar thread to some others, but as this is a production server I need to make sure what I am doing is right first time and I am still an Ubuntu novice.

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS VPS which is 250Gb SSD + 2Gb RAM. I checked with `htop` and it shows that the RAM is ticking over at over 96% used. So I was going to add a 4Gb Swapfile - but when I check the current provision it shows that there is a 512Mb swap partition.

Can someone advise how to increase the swapfile/partition to 4Gb? I was reading up about deleting the 512Mb swap partition and then creating a 4Gb swap file - or can I add a swapfile too? I dont want to destroy whats already working on the server!

I am not worried about reclaiming the 512Mb swap partition as usable disk space as I have over provisioned by a lot ;-)

This is my current disk usage;

[disk usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa8er.png)

If anyone can help I would be very grateful.

Comment: I would just go ahead and create a swap file. The system will use both of them or as you prioritize them. Assuming that your swap partition and your root file system (where you are going to create the swap file) reside on the same (or similar) SSD, you can use the same priority to both.

Comment: And please, do not post images, as you can just copy and paste the terminal output ***as a text*** in your question.

Comment: Many thanks @FedKad